# Zigzagging Flow Chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphs

I would like to have a flow chart that moves is a ZigZag from top to bottom.
I thought I could do it with a layered graph and with `orient` switching but that doesn't seem to be working for me.

So far I have:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard,graphdrawing,arrows, calc, positioning}
\usegdlibrary{layered}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=10mm,level distance=25mm,thick,
    nodes={draw,rectangle, fill=white,minimum width=30mm, minimum height=15mm, align=center,inner sep=0.5em}]


    \graph [layered layout] {%
        {gui/Circuit is \\designed in SPICE GUI}->[orient=right]
        {export/Netlist Exported \\and used to make Template in MATLAB} ->
        param/MATLAB takes Parameters->
        write_nl/ Writes Netlist to disk->
        call/Calls SPICE->
        run/Spice Simulates Circuit ->
        write_res/Writes Results to Disk ->
        read_res/ MATLAB Parses  Results from Disk->
        proc/Matlab Processes Results and Calculates Delays;

        {[same layer], gui, export};    
        {[same layer], param,write_nl,call};
        {[same layer], run,write_res};      
        {[same layer], read_res, proc};     

    };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image: Flat]

But I would like to produce (Excure the aweful cut and paste job):
[image: desired]

Comment: If you use `<-[orient=left]`, it goes in the correct direction but all the arrows end up the wrong way round!

Comment: Have you considered using the `chains` library rather than creating a graph?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As `cfr` points out the `chains` library can be used for this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[start chain=going right, every join/.style={->},
  every node/.style={draw, align=center, on chain, join, minimum height=1cm}]

\node {Circuit is \\ designed in SPICE GUI};
\node {Netlist Exported \\ and used to make Template in MATLAB};
\node [continue chain=going below] {MATLAB takes Parameters};
\node [continue chain=going left]  {Writes Netlist to disk};
\node {Calls SPICE};
\node [continue chain=going below] {Spice Simulates Circuit};
\node [continue chain=going right] {Writes Results to Disk};
\node [continue chain=going below] {MATLAB Parses  Results from Disk};
\node [continue chain=going left]  {Matlab Processes Results \\ and Calculates Delays};

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The code can be made somewhat clearer using `\foreach`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[start chain=going right, every join/.style={->},
  every node/.style={draw, align=center, on chain, join, minimum height=1cm}]

\foreach \direction/\text in {%
  right / Circuit is \\ designed in SPICE GUI,
  right / Netlist Exported \\ and used to make Template in MATLAB,
  below / Matlab takes Parameters,
  left  / Writes Netlist to disk,
  left  / Calls SPICE,
  below / Spice Simulates Circuit,
  right / Writes Results to Disk,
  below / MATLAB Parses  Results from Disk,
  left  / Matlab Processes Results \\ and Calculates Delays}
    \node [continue chain/.expanded=going \direction] {\text};

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The result is the same as before.